# ASP.NET SessionID Management

Tags: asp.net

Hi I wanted to know how the server manages session between client and server. Does the server store a sessionID per web-application and client or only per client?

Answer (score 0):

Session have following properties  [Read this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net)

```
Session is Stored  per User basis.
```

from MSDN Docs [Session in asp.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx#Background)

> Sessions are identified by a unique identifier that can be read by
>   using the SessionID property. When session state is enabled for an
>   ASP.NET application, each request for a page in the application is
>   examined for a SessionID value sent from the browser. If no SessionID
>   value is supplied, ASP.NET starts a new session and the SessionID
>   value for that session is sent to the browser with the response. By
>   default, SessionID values are stored in a cookie. However, you can
>   also configure the application to store SessionID values in the URL
>   for a "cookieless" session. A session is considered active as long as
>   requests continue to be made with the same SessionID value. If the
>   time between requests for a particular session exceeds the specified
>   time-out value in minutes, the session is considered expired. Requests
>   made with an expired SessionID value result in a new session.

Comment: I deployed two website on my local IIS server.
On one website I'm setting the session like Session["x"] = 3;
On the other application, I'm retrieving the same session, but unfortunately do not get the previous value stored in former web application.

Am i missing something?